# Managing Array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I'm new to PHP and I need help with managing with arrays. The below codes is extracting data from my SQL database. I need to know how to extract the value inside `$resultArray`. I strongly believe that `$resultArray` is an associative array, but I'm not sure how to get the value.

I tried `$result = $resultArray['ImageID'];` but it doesn't work. I'm certain its retrieving something, by printing it out on my Xcode.

```
    public function GetImage($imageurl)
    {
        $returnValue = array();
        $sql = "SELECT ImageID FROM `ImageTable` WHERE ImageURL = '$imageurl'";


        $result = $this->conn->query($sql);
        $resultArray = array();
        $tempArray = array();

        if ($result != null && (mysqli_num_rows($result) >= 1)) {

            while ($row = $result->fetch_object()) {
                $tempArray = $row;
                array_push($resultArray, $tempArray);
            }
        }
        return $resultArray;
    }
```

Comment: Try `echo "<pre>" . print_r( $resultArray, true ) . "</pre>"` to see it's structure. It should be an array of objects: `$resultArray[0]->ImageID` etc.

Comment: Introducing [var_dump](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php)—outputs content of a variable. You could try `var_dump($row)` in the line after the _while_. Then it will tell if it is an array or an object and what values it has.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not quite sure if you're using `mysqli`, but if you do then here's an answer for you:

```
$conn = new mysqli(...); // Your connection to the database
$result = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM `ImageTable` WHERE ImageURL = '$imageurl'"); // Query and get $result
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) // Extract rows (even if only one is returned)
{
     echo $row["ImageID"]; // Echoes "ImageID"-value of this row.
     // ...
}
```

Hope it helped.

Comment: I guess the OP is using `mysqli`  (mysqli_num_row)

Comment: Apologies! I didn't see you changed from fetch_object() to fetch_assoc()! It is working now.

Comment: @timmyRS However, I would like to ask, if the returned row has more than 1, say 5. Can I also use fetch_assoc() and store it inside an array? So that at later part, I can json_encode() for printing later on?

Comment: The `while()` goes trough every row and saves them as `$row`, so you can basicly go trough each `$row` with this `while()`.